# How does the Fizzbuzz algorithm work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to ask as to why when I turn `if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {console.log("Fizz")};` into `else if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {console.log("Fizz")};` vice versa, I only get Fizz and Buzz on console.log and no FizzBuzz unlike when I used if. I expect the same result with else if thus I think they should be the same?

Below is the full script for reference.

```
let answer = 100;

for (let i = 1; i <= answer; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your conditions are all wrong. It's supposed to be `Fizz` for multiples of `3`, `Buzz` for multiples of `5`, and `FizzBuzz` for multiples of both.

Comment: When you use `else if`, only the first matching condition runs. If you use `if`, each condition is checked independently.

Comment: Ah I see so if the first condition is met in this case 'Fizz' on mult of '3' then it instantly run and then the 'FizzBuzz' on 'else if' would be ignored?

Comment: This is the sort of problem that you should work out first with pencil and paper.

Comment: Just think about what the word "else" means -- "otherwise".

Comment: Your question text seems to be talking about different code than what you posted. You can't have `else if` first.

Comment: Note that checking for `i % 15 === 0` is all you need for the "FizzBuzz" case.

Answer (score 1):

forget them oldskool solutions.

IMHO the most important Array Method to learn is **Map**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Which "walks over" the Array and **returns** a new value for that Array index

```js
let arr = Array(100)
  .fill((x, div, label) => x % div ? "" : label) //store Function in every index
  .map((func, idx) =>
    func(++idx, 3, "Fizz") + func(idx, 5, "Buzz") || idx
  );
document.body.append(arr.join(", "));
```

`fill` takes a **single** Object, it is not executed 100 times!
Since JavaScript Functions are Objects this code **declares** a function **once** for every index

Note the `++idx` because we want to start at 1, not 0

In JavaScript `""+""` is a Falsy value, thus it returns the `idx` value for non-FizzBuzz numbers

More Array Methods explained: https://array-methods.github.io

Comment: This is impressive but unreadable. I wonder if "oldskool" is to be preferred!

Comment: [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) also allows for iterative transformation. (e.g. `Array.from({length: 100}, (_, idx) => {/*...*/})`), so it can perform the same task as `arr.map()` here (if the function is initialized first).

Answer (score 0):

When you use **else if** the previous **if** condition has to be false for the **else if** condition to be verified (and its content possibly executed).

Otherwise it's only a chain of indepent **if**s.

Comment: Ah it makes sense to me now, thanks for the insight I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to consider the "both case" separately, as your code does. In pseudocode:

```
if (i is divisible by 3) {
    print "Fizz"
}
if (i is divisible by 5) {
    print "Buzz"
}
```

If you run through this on paper, you can see that it will print "FizzBuzz" by executing both conditions. So it is not wrong to have a special case for both, but it is easier (and clearer) to do it without that.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `else if`, use **all conditions** as `if`

```
let answer = 100;

for (let i = 1; i <= answer; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  } 
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
  } 
  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
  } 

    console.log(i);

}
```